# Casting rules for primitive types in java

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types

In java,

There are integral types(`char`/`short`/`int`/`long`/`byte`)

There are floating types(`float`/`double`)

There is boolean type(`boolean`), not integral type, unlike C language.

Questions:

1. Is there a generic rule for casting(as per JLS) that talks, which type can be converted to another type? Out of common sense, I know that, integral and floating types casting to `boolean` is not allowed
2. Please help me understand the reasons for below output:

   ```
        /*
         * Casting rules for primitive types
         */
        double aDoubleValue = 30000000000000000000.123438934;
        int doubleToInt = (int)aDoubleValue; //stores max value 2147483647, makes sense!!
        byte doubleToByte = (byte)aDoubleValue; //stores -1, why not 127?
        short doubleToShort = (short)aDoubleValue; // stores -1, why not 32767?
        long doubleToLong = (long)aDoubleValue; // stores 9223372036854775807, makes sense!!
        float doubleToFloat = (float)aDoubleValue; // stores 3.0E19, 3.0 x 10^19  max value of float
        char doubleToChar = (char)aDoubleValue; // what does this store?
   ```

Comment: The rules for primitive types are actually stated explicitly: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2. for widening and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3 for narrowing.

Comment: @dhke why `(byte)fmax` and `(short)fmax` is -1 as per 5.1.3? any reason?

Comment: @overexchange - everything is explained there: "The results can be understood by examining the low order bits of the minimum and maximum int. The minimum int is, in hexadecimal, 0x80000000, and the maximum int is 0x7fffffff. This explains the short results, which are the low 16 bits of these values, namely, 0x0000 and 0xffff; it explains the char results, which also are the low 16 bits of these values, namely, '\u0000' and '\uffff'; and it explains the byte results, which are the low 8 bits of these values, namely, 0x00 and 0xff."

Answer (score 29):

The JLS [lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:

- byte to short, int, long, float, or double
- short to int, long, float, or double
- char to int, long, float, or double
- int to long, float, or double
- long to float or double
- float to double

Note the missing conversions from `byte` and `short` to `char`, even though `char` is two bytes long.

Everything else needs an explicit cast. [Narrowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) is a little more complex:

- `double` to `float` uses standard IEEE 754 rounding.
- integer values have their most significant bits stripped to the available width of the target type. This may result in a sign bit appearing, e.g. `(byte)0xfff == (byte)-1`;
- If the source type is floating point and the target type is `long`, the value is converted by rounding towards zero.
- If the source type is floating point and the target type is integral but not `long`, the value is first converted to `int` by rounding towards zero. Then the resulting `int` is converted to the target type using integer conversion.

Examples:

```
int doubleToInt = (int)aDoubleValue;
```

yields `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as per rounding rules.

```
byte doubleToByte = (byte)aDoubleValue;
```

first converts to `int`, yielding `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and then converts that to `byte`. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7fffffff`, hence the byte value `0xff` which is `-1`.

```
short doubleToShort = (short)aDoubleValue;
```

same again: converts to `int`, yielding `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. `0x7fffffff` to `short` yields `0xffff`, i.e. `-1`.

The tricky thing is actually the to-`char` conversion. `char` is a single, 16-bit unicode character, hence `char doubleToChar = (char)aDoubleValue` gives you `'\uffff'` by the now familiar rules.

As can be seen there is a difference between floating point and integer narrowing operations. The floating point operations do actual rounding, while the integer operations perform bitwise clamping.

The integer semantics are probably inherited from C. At least the first step of the float-to-integral narrowing ops are also what you expected. The second narrowing steps, from double/float to short, byte and char may seem a little surprising, but if you really cast float to short, you should probably double check that you know what you are doing anyway.