# Is any different to cast using (int) that using Integer.parseInt?

Tags: java, casting

Or (double) and Double.parseDouble?
When to use which ?

I've been asking me this lately

Comment: Which one you want, Int or double?

Comment: You can't cast a String to an int. You need to use `parseInt()`.

Comment: The most obvious that comes to mind is string conversion. You can't cast string to int `(int)"5"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting to an int and converting to an int, these are the questions you are trying to ask.

Integer.parseInt - used to convert a string to an Integer.
Eg: **int x = Integer.parseInt("44")** assigns 44 to x.
It will throw a number format exception if it fails to convert the string to an integer.

**int x = (int) 3.142** - assigns 3 to the value x, meaning the compiler truncates the numbers after decimal point and assigns the value 3 to the  variable x which is of type int. Here the precision of the double value will be lost.

Similarly you can use Double.parseDouble() to convert a String to a double.

Answer (score 1):

Using casts like `(double)` can convert one similar type to another similar type (any number to a double), `Double.parseDouble()` is used to convert different types to a `double` (I think it might just be String.class to double I could be wrong). If you want to convert a type to a `Double` object you can use `Double.valueOf()`, the difference is that `Double.parseDouble()` returns the primitive type while `Double.valueOf()` returns a new instance of `Double.class`.

Comment: Would like to note that converting to a String is somewhat different, you could do `"" + ((int) x)` or `String.valueOf()` or `Object.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

parseInt and parseDouble are used to convert a String to a double. This is not possible with a cast (i.e. (int)"123").

A cast is used to convert a variable of one type to a variable of another type. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776256/casting-rules-for-primitive-types-in-java) discusses what types can be cast to other types, including casting to int.