# Typecasting int to float before division. Which casts do I really need and which can I remove and why?

Tags: java, types, casting

When dividing by ints and I want the result to be a float I can end up with something like this.

```
float ratio = landscape ? 
              ((float) image.getWidth()) / ((float)image.getHeight()) : 
              ((float)image.getHeight()) / ((float)image.getWidth());
```

However I think I don't need every cast. When diving sometimes it seems to be auto casted. What are the rules, when does this happen?

Comment: You only need to cast one of each number in division because any float/int = float. Take a look at this SO question for a better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776990/4307644

Comment: casting one of the operand is enough

Comment: Also keep in mind that a `float` cannot represent all integer values exactly. If precision matters, use `double`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to cast at least *one* operand per division. The other operand will be promoted automatically.

I'd personally extract local variables though, at which point it's all implicit (which is why I'd have a comment):

```
// Use floating point promotion to avoid integer division
float width = image.getWidth();
float height = image.getHeight();
float ratio = landscape ? width / height : height / width;
```

Answer (score 2):

For each division, you need only 1.
So it should be:

```
float ratio = landscape ?
              ((float)image.getWidth() / image.getHeight()) :
              ((float)image.getHeight() / image.getWidth());
```